# joining three tables and displaying information in two locations

Tags: php, mysql, sections

```
//Table One {news}
Id1 | subject1 | url1 | source1

//Table Two {blog_news}
order_id | type | id1 | id

//Table Three {blog}
id | name | subject | url

//SQL query
SELCET nf.*, fnb.*, b.id, b.name, b.subject, b.url FROM news AS nf JOIN blog_news AS fnb ON nf.id1=fnb.id1 JOIN blog AS b ON fnb.id=b.id
```

```
//Display Code

if(($i = 0; $i <= 5; ++$i)&&(fnb.type' ==1)){

//Order the result by 'order_id'

//Table Display Code
<table>
 <tr> 
  <td width='250px' valign='middle' align='left'>
     <font size='-2'>
     <a herf='” . $_GET['b.url'] . “'>
     <b>” . $_GET ['b.subject'] . “</b>
     </a>
     </font>
   </td>
   <td width='100px' valign='middle' align='right'>
       <font size='-2'>
       <a herf='” . $_GET['b.url'] . “'>
       <b>” . $_GET ['b.name'] . “</b>
       </a>
       </font>
     </td> 
   </tr> 
 </table> 
 }endif
```

What I'm trying to accomplished, is joining three database table together and display results in two areas using the code similar to the `{//display}` code section.

I've tried may different method to accomplish this task.
I tried to use a while loop in php to display the result and I received an `mysql_fetch_error()` before the while loop started. My goal is to also have each table to order by `order_id` in `DESC` order.

Comment: If you problem is as your title sugests, you need to realize, that mysql query result is only a temporary thing. never holds more than 1 row at a time and you can not go back to rows you already went through unless you a) buffer the result (store the rows as they go - to an array for example) or b) use some output buffering which means, you will prepare the part of your page you want to see lower down on your page at the time you are processing your table records - eg. instead of `print $row['x'];` you will do `$buffer.=$row['x'];` and much later on when the time comes: `print $buffer;`.

Answer (score 0):

It is far easier to organize the data in MySQL.

Try this:

```
SELECT nf.*, fnb.*, b.id, b.name, b.subject, b.url
FROM news nf
  JOIN blog_news fnb ON nf.id1 = fnb.id1
  JOIN blog b ON fnb.id = b.id
WHERE fnb.type = 1
ORDER BY fnb.order_id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

And take a look at how MySQL's [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) works.

If you do not know how to interface with MySQL in php, a quick search on your favorite search engine for "MySQL and php tutorial" should help.